# How does the Lambda function work on lists in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, lambda

I have this line of code and don't quite understand why the outcome is `[False, False]`

```
i :: [Bool]
i = filter (\x-> (not x)) [False,False,True,True,True]
```

I thought it would come out to `[True,True,True]`.

Would really appreciate a short explanation of the Outcome here. Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you think the result of `filter (\x-> x) [False,False,True,True,True]` would be?

Comment: `filter p xs` is not the same as `filter id (map p xs)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:filter),

> `filter`, applied to a predicate and a list, returns the list of those elements that satisfy the predicate, i.e. [...]:
>
> ```
> >>> filter odd [1, 2, 3]
> [1,3]
> ```

The expression that defines `i` is essentially saying:

> Filter the booleans `x` for which `not x` is `True` from the list `[False, False, True, True, True]`

- For the first entry, `not False` is `True`, so it is retained.
- For the second entry, `not False` is again `True`, so this is retained as well.
- For the remaining three entries, `not True` is `False`, so these
  entries are dropped.

The result is `[False, False]`.

Answer (score 2):

Because `filter` keeps the elements where the predicate is true. These elements are now `False, False`.